# Sticky Footer Appearing Slightly Below Fold

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I'm trying to implement a sticky footer such as [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) but if my content is shorter than the footer still appears partially past the fold. I can see about 25px of it and I have to scroll down to see the rest. Here is the relevant CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
}
.wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}

.footer, .wrapper:after {height: 60px;}
```

I'm using Chrome but the problem also exists in Safari. I've tried it without using pseudo selectors but I have similar issues. All of my content is wrapped in the wrapper div except for the footer.

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." This cannot be reproduced without the relevant HTML.

Comment: Do you have vertical margins anywhere? If so, that's likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical margins will cause issues when using sticky footer because of how `height` is calculated, which can be seen here: **http://jsfiddle.net/b9Zy7/**

Change `margin-top` to `padding-top` on `p` and all is well.